# author year, same year, different papers, same author, not a,b output

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am facing problem on not getting X2017a, X2017b type of author-year format citation, instead even if two different article in same year by same author, I am getting X2017 output in the pdf file.

I am using

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

you can try with

```
@article{Korda2018a,
title = {Linear predictors for nonlinear dynamical systems: {K}oopman operator meets model predictive control},
journal = {Automatica},
volume = {93},
pages = {149-160},
year = {2018},
issn = {0005-1098},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2018.03.046},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000510981830133X},
author = {Milan Korda and Igor Mezić}
}
@article{Korda2018b,
  title={Learning {K}oopman eigenfunctions for prediction and control: the transient case},
  author={Korda, Milan and Mezic, Igor},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1810.08733},
  year={2018}
}
```

Many Thanks for your help.

In case If you wanted to see the full set of usepacakges I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\let\plll\lll 
\let\lll\relax
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=10cm, top=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{green!55!black}(#1)}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
\newcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{green!55!black}}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{20, 180, 150}
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=myblue,urlcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue,}
\makeindex
\parindent0mm
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
```

Comment: Does your .bib file indeed have once "Mezić" (with accent) and once "Mezic" (without accent?)

Comment: May I suggest you spell the second author's surname as `Mezi{\'c}` in both entries? That way, BibTeX won't get tripped up by the presence of the non-ASCII character `ć`.

Comment: Off-topic: It's not appropriate to use the `@article` entry type for the `Korda2018b` entry. I'd suggest using the `@unpublished` entry type instead -- and changing the entry's `journal` field to `note`. Oh, and since the `apalike` bib style is ancient -- it predates the creation of the Internet by several years -- don't be surprised that fields named `issn`, `doi`, and `url` will all be ignored.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thanks it worked

Comment: @Mico Thanks it worked

Comment: instead of apalike what should I use if I want to print author year type in my output pdf?

Comment: @Marso - "Authoryear-style" addresses merely the formatting of the citation call-outs, but doesn't narrow down how the bibliographic entries should be formatted. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of bibliography styles out there on the Internet that are capable of producing authoryear-style citation call-outs. Which one to select depends crucially on how they format the bibliographic entries -- a criterion about which you haven't said a lot so far.